# Neo4j Bolt is not consistently processing Cypher queries

Tags: python, neo4j

I am trying to use Bolt to write to a remote machine, Machine 1, that is running Neo4j 3.0 server. Machine 1 has port 7687 open. If I create a test node by logging into Machine 1 and using the browser interface:

```
CREATE (:TestNode {Name:"Test"})
```

and then run my script on my local machine, Machine 2:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://Machine1.com:7687",
                              auth=basic_auth("neo4j","password"))
session = driver.session()

#Clear what's already there
session.run("OPTIONAL MATCH(n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r")
session.run("MATCH (n:TestNode) DELETE n")
```

then I can see in the browser interface on Machine 1 that the node has been removed from the graph. So far, so good.

However, the rest of my script on Machine 2, which creates several thousand nodes and edges, appears to run successfully, but when I look on Machine 1 I am stuck with an empty graph. I know there is no problem with the Cypher statement's I am using because they all came from a previous sucessful (but slow) py2neo script. Is there any way to see a detailed log of what's happening? I see no evidence of any connection in Machine 1's Neo4j log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say for sure what solved this problem, but it was a combination of restoring the stock neo4j.conf file, clearing the ~/.neo4j/known_hosts file, and probably most importantly moving from py2neo to the supported neo4j python driver.